# Making a convenient logging function for Try[T], but got stuck because of the type system

Tags: scala, casting, type-conversion, scala-generics

I wonder if this can be done using Scala's type system.

Basically, I want to make a logging method which accepts a `result` of type `Try[T]` and prints out a message that differs a bit depending whether `result` is a `Success` or a `Failure`

For example, the signature might look like

```
def logTry[T](what: Try[T], block: T => String): Unit
```

and can be used as such:

```
val size: Try[(Int, Int)] = Try(getSizeAndTimestampFromDatabase())
logTry(size, e => "size is " + e._2 + " kb")
```

which will output

`size is 13 kb` if `size` is `Success(x: Int)`, e.g., `Success(13)`

or

`error: size is (not available)` if `size` if of type `Failure(t: Throwable)`

The tricky part is that we need to be able to access the object within the `Try` for printing to the screen if it's a `Success`, or print a chosen default string (e.g. "(not available)") if it's a `Failure` as the placeholder. Also, it must work with a very general type `T` or `Any` that can range from a simple scalar value to an instance of a class, etc.

The use case for this eccentric function is that it will be very handy for logging a Try object in an informative way, without cluttering the code with map / recover or a match statement.

This is the skeleton that I have came up with, but of course the hard part hasn't been figured out yet.

```
def logTry[T](what: Try[T], block: T => String): Unit = {
  what match {
    case Success(res) => println(block(res))
    case Failure(t) => println(???) // how to do this
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the solution, which not forces you to explicitly supply types:

```
implicit class LogTry[T](attempt: Try[T]) {
  def log[E](comp: T => E, block: String => String, error: Throwable => String = _ => "(N/A)") =
    println(block(attempt map (comp andThen (_.toString)) recover { case ex => error(ex) } get))
}
```

use it as

```
size.log(_._2, size => f"size is $size kb")
```

or

```
size.log(_._2, size => f"size is $size kb", err => f"(not available because $err)")
```

Comment: It's not concise enough, imagine if we can do this `logTry[(Int,Int)](size, e => f"size is ${e._2} kb")` and get a very sensible output, i.e.  `size is (N/A) kb` - unavailable value will automatically be replaced with a "placeholder"

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do (well, if I didn't use implicits to add the method to `Try`):

```
def logTry[T](t: Try[T])(f: Try[T] => String) { println(f(t)) }

val size: Try[Integer] = Try(getSizeFromDatabase())
logTry(size) {
    case Success(e) => s"size is $e kb"
    case Failure(e) => s"error: size is (${e.getMessage}})"
}
```

Edit: after understanding your request

```
def logTry(t: Try[Any], f: Any => String) {
    t match {
        case Success(e) => println(f(e))
        case Failure(e) => println(f(new Object {
            override def toString = "(not available)"
        }))
    }
}

val size: Try[Integer] = Try(getSizeFromDatabase())
logTry(size, s => s"Size is $s kb")
```

I don't know of a way to achieve for a generic type T, but I don't think that's a good idea anyway: it's possible for the client to make special use of the methods of T when printing, but you want it to always print "not available" where it was supposed to print the information from T, and that's not so simple.

Another option is to create a special formatter (think `"size is ${...} kb"`) so the logger would know how to replace it, but I'm not sure if this is what you want.

Comment: If we do it like this, we will force the user of our function to handle the Success and Failure case explicitly. Also, the error/success message must be either written twice, or be declared as a separate val if we want to avoid duplication. With my function, we provide a sensible placeholder for when the value is not available

Comment: What placeholder do you provide? I see ??? in care of an error. If you just wanted to print "error", why not do that in your original implementation?

Comment: just FYI, `???` is a valid  method in `Predef` https://twitter.com/sw1nn/status/193045408996524032

Comment: ??? is an alias for "throw new NotImplementedError", which I interpreted as "I don't know what to do here". If you want to receive the string from the outside, you can do as @Odomontois suggested below me.

Comment: I put it there since I'm figuring out how to implement that part. The output that I want should be `size is 13 kb` or `error: size is (not available) kb`.

Comment: Ah, no I understand :)